# How can I make a Dataframe from a dict that maps (column, row) index pairs to values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

Using pandas, given this dictionary which has tuples as keys:

`dictionary = {(a,c): 1, (a,d): 3, (b,c): 2, (b,d): 4}`

How can I get a dataframe like so?

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c | 1 | 2 |
| d | 3 | 4 |

I thought about using `df.at[]` to assign the correct values to each row/column location - e.g. `df.at[a,c] = 1`.
However, I'm not clear on how to use the tuple with `.at[]`.

Comment: `df.at[key] = value`? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please add the tag for it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: What should go into cells that *aren't* specified by the dictionary? What column dtypes should be used?

Comment: @wjandrea as far as I'm aware, Pandas is the only Python library that uses the name "dataframe" for a type that it creates.

Comment: Hi wjandrea! I'm using Pandas. Thanks for your help, I'll give df.at[key] = value a try. Sorry if it was a basic question, I'm a beginner at coding

Comment: @Karl Polars also has a [`DataFrame`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html). Although, if people don't mention it, I assume they're using Pandas, but I like to ask to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

I would make a MultiIndex [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) using the *constructor*, then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) it's *outer-level* :

```
dictionary = {("a", "c"): 1, ("a", "d"): 3, ("b", "c"): 2, ("b", "d"): 4}

df = pd.Series(dictionary).unstack(0)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   a  b
c  1  2
d  3  4
```

Comment: Should add that if the dtypes were different per column, you'd want a different approach. But this works well where they're all ints.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your dictionary and create a new dictionary of dictionaries, where the outer dictionary's keys are column names and the inner dictionaries' keys are the row indices. To save on a few lines of code, I'm going to use a `defaultdict(dict)` as the outer dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {('a','c'): 1, ('a','d'): 3,
              ('b','c'): 2, ('b','d'): 4}


dd = defaultdict(dict)

for (col_name, row_name), value in dictionary.items():
    dd[col_name][row_name] = value
```

This results in the following `dd`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'a': {'c': 1, 'd': 3}, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 4}})
```

Finally, use this to create your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd)
```

Which gives the desired dataframe:

```
   a  b
c  1  2
d  3  4
```

Comment: Nice! This is a better approach than what OP had in mind; cf. this other SO question: [Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, and then filling it](/q/13784192/4518341)